# Adding multiple icons to a single csv layer

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, csv

I am loading the NumberIcon1 image for every point added through the csv file, is it possible to loop through the images so that way they go in order like NumberIcon 2 for the second point in the csv file and so on.

```
    layer1 = new CSVLayer("2.5_week.csv", {
      copyright: "USGS.gov"
  });
  var marker[] = new PictureMarkerSymbol("resources/markers/red/NumberIcon1.png", 20, 20);
  var renderer = new SimpleRenderer(marker);
  layer1.setRenderer(renderer);
  var template = new InfoTemplate("${type}", "${place}");
  layer1.setInfoTemplate(template);
  map.addLayer(layer1);
```

Comment: What is the question? Did you try it and it didn't work the way you expected? If so, what were you expecting and what happened instead?

Comment: Well whenever you add the marker onto the map if you have more than one location coming in from a csv file all the points will be labeled with the same marker. So if i have twenty locations in my csv file they will all have the Number 1 on them. Is there a way to change this so that way it loops through the icons that i have in my folder and labels them in order of  the location read?

Comment: Please edit the question with those key points. If there are a lot of comments, the detail will be lost.